# How do I calculate the time t taken for a value to reach x(t) given exponential growth?

Tags: exponential-function

There are many challenges on Facebook, of the form:

> for each day of N days you must perform a given task and on each day nominate one friend to also take part in the challenge

So, every time someone completes the challenge, they should have invited N friends to also take part in the challenge (one for each day).

Given the above, if x(t) is the number of people invited to the challenge at time t in days, how can I calculate t for any given x(t) assuming x(0) = 1?

For example, how can I calculate how many days it would take for 1 million invites to have happened?

I'm guessing this is going to involve a modified form of the exponential growth equation:

$$ 
x(t) = x_0 × (1 + r)^t
$$

But as I understand, applying this only works if the N friends are all invited on the first day of a challenge...

Comment: You might find it easier to calculate the numbers involved for $N=1$, $2$ and $3$

Answer (score 0):

The number of people doubles each day, so if we start counting with just you on day zero, there are $2^n$ people on day $n$.  Given the number of people $p$, to find $n$ you take the base $2$ log.  $n=\log_2 p$